# line-height vs. font-size/line-height

Tags: font-size, css

If in a font-size: CSS attribute you encounter font-size: 14px/19px, that's the same thing as saying font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px, isn't it?

If so then why aren't the following two paragraph tags the same height?:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/line-height.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you have `font-size: 14px/19px;` which is invalid. I think you mean `font: 14px/19px;` But this is still wrong...

When using the CSS shorthand for font, you cannot omit the size or family values.

Try `font: 14px/19px Arial;`

See the *Omitted Mandatory Values* section of http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-primer-on-the-css-font-shorthand-property/ for more info.

Comment: Yep, nailed it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I've updated it but they're still looking different.. any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to make sure the `font-family` is the same for both paragraphs. Arial is not the default browser font. Try `font: 14px/19px Times;`

Comment: @neubert, `font-face` is not a CSS property; use `font-family` instead.